# Enviar e pegar GET por URL AMIGAVEL

Tags: php, url, get, url-amigável, url-rewrite

Tenho essa tag na index

```
<a href="projeto">Projeto</a>
```

Que me manda para essa pagina

> localhost/projeto.php

Que estou deixando assim

> localhost/projeto

Com o

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
DirectoryIndex home.php home.html index.php index.html
```

Mas agora preciso passar duas variáveis pela url, ficaria da seguinte forma

```
<a href="projeto?id=25&nome=aqui_vai_o_nome">Projeto</a>
```

Mas preciso que a URL fique dessa maneira

> localhost/projeto/25/aqui_vai_o_nome

Lembrando que depois preciso pegar esses dois dados dentro da pagina PROJETO

Esse é o codigo do projeto.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <?php include('include/baseHead-2.php'); ?>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->    
    <?php include('include/fonts.php'); ?>
    <?php include('include/css-2.php'); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include('include/topbar-2.php'); ?>
    <div class="container-flex m-primary container-title-page">
        <div class="container py-80">
            <div><h1 class="ff-os">Titulo da pagina</h1></div>
            <div><h2 class="ff-os"><a href="../../home" class="ff-os">Home</a> / Pagina atual</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container py-100 container-*">
        <div class="row h-200px">
            <?php
                echo $_GET['id'];
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('include/footer-2.php'); ?>
</body>

<?php include('include/js-2.php'); ?>

</html>
```

Esse é meu .htaccess e o novo projeto.php onde não esta recebendo o $_GET

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^projeto\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ projeto.php?id=$1&nome=$2

DirectoryIndex home.php home.html index.php index.html
```

**projeto.php - "projeto/15/nome"**

```
<?php

    echo $_GET['id']."</br>";
    echo $_GET['nome'];

?>
```

Comment: Infelizmente, não consigo ver o que está errado. Se você quiser eu posso criar uma outra resposta com um outro tipo de estrutura para você testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^projeto\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ projeto.php?id=$1&nome=$2

DirectoryIndex home.php home.html index.php index.html
```

Esta linha abaixo:

```
RewriteRule ^projeto\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ projeto.php?id=$1&nome=$2
```

Cria uma regra diferente, apenas no caso da URL começar com `projeto`.

Para pegar o id e o nome basta usar o `$_GET['id']` e o `$_GET['nome']` dentro do arquivo `projeto.php`

Se você clicar em:

```
<a href="projeto/15/nome_do_projeto">ver projeto</a>
```

Em `projeto.php` você poderá visualizar usando o `echo`:

```
   echo $_GET['id']."</br>";
   echo $_GET['nome'];
```

Retorno:

```
15
nome_do_projeto
```

**EDIT: Problemas para acessar outros arquivos**

Quando você usa url amigáveis é necessário colocar o caminho completo de onde a imagem, arquivos css e js estão. No seu caso ficaria assim, um exemplo:

```
<img src="http://localhost/imagem/imagemExemplo.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="http://localhost/res/style/estilo.css" media="screen" />
```

geralmente eu crio uma constante e uso ela em todo o site:

```
define("URL", "http://localhost/");
<link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href='<?php echo URL; ?>/style/estilo.css' media='screen' />
```

Assim fica mais fácil, pois quando publicar o site, basta alterar a url.

**Edite 2:**

Altere o `.htaccess` para:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^projeto\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ projeto.php?id=$1&nome=$2

DirectoryIndex home.php home.html index.php index.html
```